# Parallelized Update of MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, r, parallel-processing, plyr

I am using R to manage a MySQL database and ran into the following question: Can I use multiple cores to run an update on a table, or does SQL get confused by that? The R code I use works like this (pseudocode):

```
d_ply(.data = my_local_table, .variables = ~ID, .fun = function(x){
    check if ID exists in my_DB_table
    if(exists):
        Update record
    else:
        Create new record
```

Is it problematic to use the .parallel option of the `plyr` package in this case?

Comment: MySQL, like other relational databases, is built with concurrency in mind. You can, but since you are checking if an ID exists in your db - that's wrong approach. You are subject to wrong information. You need to create unique index on your table and just insert, not check whether it exists and then insert - the reason for this is that there exists a tiny lag between R and MySQL so by the time you check whether something is in - another process can create the record. We protect against that by using unique indexes and just inserting. If it fails, we know it exists.

Comment: Thanks @Mjh, the problems you describe are exactly the ones I had in mind when posing this question. `ID` is actually the primary key of the my_DB_table and thus holds only unique records. However, if I don't check for existence I don't know whether to `UPDATE` or to `INSERT`. Should I use something like `try(INSERT) catch (UPDATE)`?

Comment: MySQL extends SQL by implementing `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` which fits your case perfectly, if I'm not mistaken. You can google for what I wrote in the syntax, you'll get entire manual page devoted to it. It does exactly what you wrote, except the entire query is handled by MySQL without you having to catch an exception.